# vk mini apps параметры запуска

Tags: react-native, vk-mini-apps

Помогите как сделать так что, если человек заходит по ссылки vk.com/appTEST#perexod
Менялась активная панель, точнее открывалась нужная, правильное ли выражение ниже и как получить этот location.hash при запуске

```js
if (window.location.hash === "#perexod"){
setActivPanel = "perexod"

}
```